# Index Match Validation from two files

Tags: python

I would like to ask for your help on creating a code that essentially perform a test on matching the values from two files/sheets. Im trying to use merge but it is not successful.

Below is a screenshot of the sample expected output

[image]

Comment: Have you tried any code?
Show what you have done so far!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
x = []
for value1 in sheet1:
    for value2 in sheet2:
        if value1 == value2:
            x.append(value1)
```

returns all matching values in two sheets